# Tab Bar Controller doesn't show the tab bar items all at the same time

Tags: ios7, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

I've inserted 5 tab bar items into a tab bar that got inserted when I inserted a Tab Bar Controller. But the problem is that I can show only 1 item at one time.

Here is the view hierarchy of my tab bar items:

[image]

And in the interface builder, it shows only one item:

[image]

I've also tried selecting all the tab bar items but unable to see them simultaneously. Any help???

Edit: I'm using Xcode 5 with xib files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert UITabBarController into storyboard and your UIViewControllers and then Ctrl-drag from the TabBarControler to each ViewController and select Reletainship Segue->View Controllers.

This way each ViewController will get a tabBar in the bottom and your will adjust its name and icon individidually on the ViewControllers. On the tabBarController you can adjust their order just by dragging the icons into their desired positions.

[image]

Comment: I can't use storyboards, I'm following a book that uses xib files. So is there anyway to do the same task with xib file???